# Sudo and wifi not working in newer kernel version

Tags: boot, networking, wireless, kernel

(I am running Ubuntu 18.04. Default kernel is 5.4.0-65-generic)

When I boot up my computer with the newest kernel (5.4.x), things does not work properly. Commands with sudo won't run, they just hang forever. Some commands without sudo also have trouble running. Of the commands I have tried running,  commands related to wireless networking e.g. `nmcli d wifi connect <name of wifi> password <password for wifi>` are most often problematic. Wifi is not automatically connected when I boot my pc with 5.4.x kernel, and I can't even manage to connect it manually either, commands will just give a timeout or hang forever and I am not able to connect to a wifi through the gnome-control-center (gnome settings).

However, I figured out that if while booting my computer up and pressing SHIFT, choosing "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and then select one of the oldest kernels (Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-26-generic, or Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-47-generic (either one works the same)), everythings works properly: wifi connects automatically, sudo commands work etc...

I use a USB wifi adapter and have had problems configuring that with ubuntu before, but since even commands in the terminal (also in tty3 - tty6), I don't think there USB adapter is the reason for the problems.

I can understand that a new kernel update might cause wifi to not work anymore, especially since I use a USB wifi adapter, but when hardly any commands will run, I am clueless of what the source to all these problems are.

Any help will be very greatly appreciated!